# How to match values of one vector tp values of another vector with tolerance?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector

```
c(0.399999999999977, 0.000399999999899592, 0, 0, 1.00239999999985)
```

I expect the values to be equal to integers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. However, this equality is subject to a tolerance of let's say 0.1. I would like to receive a new vector of matched integer values. In cases where a values of input vector does not correspond to the values it is matched against I would like to get an NA (e.g. 0.3999 does not correspond to to the 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 integers with tolerance of < 0.1)

```
c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
vec <- c(0.399999999999977, 0.000399999999899592, 0, 0, 1.00239999999985)
ifelse( abs(vec - round(vec)) <= 0.1, round(vec), NA)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this gives the right answer if `vec` contains a number like `99999.015`. It seems to return `99999` but I would expect `NA`.

Comment: @SamR probably a protection mask like `round(vec) %in% 0:4` can solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
> round(v) * NA^(!abs(round(v) - v) <= 0.1)
[1] NA  0  0  0  1
```

or limit the mapping within the range `0:4` (if needed)

```
> round(v) * NA^(!abs(round(v) - v) <= 0.1 & round(v) %in% 0:4)
[1] NA  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Round and check remainder

```
x=c(0.399999999999977,0.000399999999899592,0,0,1.00239999999985)
x2=round(x,2)
ifelse(x2%%1==0,x2,NA)
[1] NA  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: nice answer, +1! but it would be better to make it generalized, e.g., `tol = 0.15`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which uses `outer()` and returns a named vector:

```r
x <- c(0.399999999999977, 0.000399999999899592, 0, 0, 1.00239999999985)
to_match <- 0:4
m <- outer(x, to_match, \(x, y, tol = 0.1) abs(x - y) < tol)

to_match[apply(m, 1, \(row) ifelse(sum(row) > 0, which.max(row), NA))] |>
    setNames(x)

#    0.399999999999977 0.000399999999899592                    0                    0     1.00239999999985
#                   NA                    0                    0                    0                    1
```

Note that this can be generalised to any numeric values, rather than just integers. If, for example, we have the following values which should match:

```r
x  <- 99999.015
to_match  <- 99999.06
```

Using `round()` can give unexpected results:

```r
# I would not expect this
ifelse( abs(x - round(x)) <= 0.1, round(x), NA)
# [1] 99999

# This is the expected output - but we don't compare to to_match
# so only works for integers (which the question did specify)
x2=round(x,2)
ifelse(x2%%1==0,x2,NA) # 0
# [1] NA

# This approach allows to match non-integers
m <- outer(x, to_match, \(x, y, tol = 0.1) abs(x - y) < tol)
to_match[apply(m, 1, \(row) ifelse(sum(row) > 0, which.max(row), NA))] |>
    setNames(x)
# 99999.015 
#  99999.06
```